# JPA Postgres - Unable to convert dynamic JSON to Java Type

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

Consider the scenario, where I have a postgres table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_json_data(
    t_id int,
    payload jsonb,
    primary key (t_id)
);
```

In this table, i will store json data in the 'payload' column. BUT, I intend to store any structured-JSON data here.
For example some rows may have the following data:

```
"{\"name\": \"person1\", \"age\": \"30\"}"
```

And there may be other rows that will store JSON such as:

```
"{\"systemName\": \"System1\", \"log\": \"main\", \"returnCode\": \"200\" }"
```

The problem i have is that when defining JPA entity, I would have to define the type to be jsonB and possibly the structure. However, the structure of the JSON in the payload will be different.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_json_data")
public class JsonDataEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "t_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id

    // JSONB type? (using a string doesn't work)

}
```

Things that have been tried:

1. I thought about retrieving the jsonb data as a string from JPA, but it turns out that Postgres is very strict about this. Trying this causes exceptions to be thrown. Although I think this option is favourable.

Any advice would be appreciated, or at least a direction to what to look at would be grateful. thanks

Comment: This might help: https://vladmihalcea.com/map-string-jpa-property-json-column-hibernate/

Comment: thanks @sagarr that worked great.